# What does a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ mean? What is the difference between $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I keep seeing that $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the set of all $n$ sized 'ordered' tuples or whatever.

And then it says that a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a list of ordered $n$ elements. What is the difference? They sound exactly the same?

And can someone explain the difference between the $0$ vector and $0$ matrix and additive identity?

Comment: A set of all possible such vectors vs. one such vector.

Comment: Also remember that with vectors there are the notion of addition and multiplication of scalars. These operations are not present when considering the set $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: It's not a "list of ordered $n$ elements"; it's an ordered list of $n$ elements. I.e. it is the list that is ordered; each element separately is not ordered.

Comment: As a side note, I would not put "ordered" in quotes, this is an essential aspect of the definition. In applied mathematics (e.g. studying variation in some physical quantity as a function of $T$ temperature $V$ volume and $P$ pressure) we might write $f(T,V,P) = f(V,P,T)$ or any other ordering for a function of a tuple without regard to the order of the variables because the variables are distinguishable by physical significance. This is not possible in abstract $\mathbb{R}^n$ where order matters. $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ are different, we aren't just putting the same $1$ in another place

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but I think you might like this short video *Vectors, what even are they?* that discusses at least three different ways to think about vectors: https://youtu.be/fNk_zzaMoSs

Comment: @SammyBlack thanks for the link, but this video doesn't matter R^N. What's the difference between a vector in R^N and the vector he's describing?

Answer (score 3):

As you say, $\mathbb R^n$ is **the set of all** ordered $n$-tuples of real numbers.

A vector in $\mathbb R^n$ is **just one** ordered $n$-tuple of real numbers.

Comment: Sometimes people visualize "vectors" as geometric objects, commonly depicted as arrows, which might or might not have the beginning of the arrow placed at the origin. When the base of the arrow is not at the origin there can be an issue of interpretation as to what the vector "is" or where it "is," versus what it is represented by. The question might be getting at this. But certainly in formal treatments a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is just an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @leslietownes : Regardless of whether you think of a vector as a tuple or as an arrow, $\mathbb R^n$ is the set of ALL vectors in a space, whereas each vector is only ONE vector.

Comment: I absolutely agree and upvoted your clear and concise answer. I was just commenting on a feature of the question that may not have been express in the question. (Honestly, who knows.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy still quite confused, can you update your answer with some examples of what you mean and explain more? like show me examples of R^N versus vectors in R^N and some more context?

Comment: @ShahJacob : $(3,-8,10)$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^3.$ And $(-1,6,9)$ is another vector in $\mathbb R^3.$ The space $\mathbb R^3$ is the set of _all_ such vectors. Each such vector is a member of $\mathbb R^3,$ which is a set with infinitely many members. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

Vectors can be added and be multiplied by scalars.  $R^n$ consists of points in an n-dimensional coordinate system, without any arithmetic involved.

Two-d example: vector $\overrightarrow{(1,2)}$ can be any place.  You could place the tail at (5,3) and the head will be at (6,5).  This different from the point (1,2).

Comment: couple of questions, 1st) what do you mean by 'this is different from the point (1, 2). what is different from the point (1,2). how is that 1,2 with the arrow different from (1,2). also 2nd question, what is an n-dimensional coordinate system? and 3rd), can you write some more examples of vectors in R^N versus just R^n alone

Comment: A point has only one attribute - its location.  There is no arithmetic involved.  A vector has length and direction, and has no particular location, but it is subject to arithmetic - addition, subtraction, and scalar multiplication.  The notation (unfortunately - that is the source of the confusion) is the same for both - that an an ordered array of n numbers $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ for either a point in n dimensions or an n-dimensional vector.  I put an arrow over the vector to emphasize the difference between the concepts.  In practice usually people don't bother.